# Logstash .odx file input

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file, logstash-input-jdbc

I was hoping someone could help me regarding input in **logstash**.

I am very new to `logstash` and I have a requirement where my `logstash` input file is an unconventional file.

How do I input an ODX input file? I think delimiter for the input file is `#` as we'd like to treat those with `#` as Columns/Fields.

Sample data:

```
'#Customer Market

250

'#Date of Export

Mon Jan 20 08:41:12 2020

'#Current Device

DigiMarkXP

'#Taskcounter

1


'#----- Start Task -----



'#Location

FoodMarket_001\Grocery_XXX\118_Cust

'#Customer ID

 0118

'#Cashier Counter

1

'#Counter Name

DigiMarkXP

'#Items

20
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please improve the formatting of the question. Wrap the code in '``` ... ``` ' brackets.

Comment: Consider linking a related section of the Logstash documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html